# If $f(0) < f(2)$ ,then $f([0,2])$ must be equal to $[f(0),f(2)]$ True/false

Tags: real-analysis

Given $ f : [0,2] \rightarrow (0,2)$ is  a continious  mapping

Is the following statement is true/false ?

If  $f(0)  < f(2)$ ,then  $f([0,2])$  must be  equal to  $[f(0),f(2)]$

My attempt  :  Yes ,[image]I take $f(x) = x$ , then  its obviously  satisfied  , Again i take  $f(x) =x^3$,, then also   its obviously  satisfied

Is its true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not True.

For example, consider a quadratic function $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$. Now, using simultaneous equations , find $a,b,c$ such that $f(0) = 0.5$, $f(2) = 0.6$ and $f(1) = 1$. If need be, multiply by a non-zero constant to ensure that the range fits in $(0,2)$, and you have your counterexample, because $f(1) \notin [f(0),f(2)]$.

The intermediate value theorem only tells you that $[f(0),f(2)]$ is *contained* in $f([0,2])$ : there could be more points in the second set.

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't. Take $f(x)= 1+\frac{x(x-2)}{2}+\varepsilon x$ as counterexample.

Comment: That function's image isn't contained in $(0,2)$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: you are absolutely right. Although, the question has already be answered for the sake of consistency I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: @maxmilgram  how  u find that  function ?. i mean how u appraoched ?

Comment: Basically I searched for a function where $f(0)=f(2)$ which is not constant. The easiest function I could think of was a parabola.

Comment: What is the point of searching a function where $f(0)=f(2)$ here ? The hypothesis states clearly that we must have $f(0)<f(2)$.

Comment: @nicomezi not sure if the OP was edited or I have a reading impairment. Anyways thanks for the clarification. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ is not required to be strictly increasing on $[0,2]$.